# Error: The operrator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: flutter, function, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I saw that there in another post about the same error but it was  solved by just adding () next to the data keyword, I tried it but still showing error.

```dart
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
    }

    
    class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {  LocationPermission? permission;
      late  Position _currentPosition;
    
      final CollectionReference sellersCollectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sellers');
    
      Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> getSellers() async {
        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> sellers = [];
        await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
            .then((Position position) async {
          _currentPosition = position;
          QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await sellersCollectionReference.get();
          if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document in querySnapshot.docs) {
              double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
                _currentPosition.latitude,
                _currentPosition.longitude,
                document.data()['latitude'],
                document.data()['longitude'],
              );
              if (distance / 1000 <= 3) {
                sellers.add(document);
              }
            }
          }
        });
        return sellers;

    
      }

        final items = [
    
          "slider/0.jpg",
          "slider/1.jpg",
          "slider/2.jpg",
          "slider/3.jpg",
          "slider/4.jpg",
          "slider/5.jpg",
          "slider/6.jpg",
          "slider/7.jpg",
          "slider/8.jpg",
          "slider/9.jpg",
          "slider/10.jpg",
          "slider/11.jpg",
          "slider/12.jpg",
          "slider/13.jpg",
          "slider/14.jpg",
          "slider/15.jpg",
          "slider/16.jpg",
          "slider/17.jpg",
          "slider/18.jpg",
          "slider/19.jpg",
          "slider/20.jpg",
          "slider/21.jpg",
          "slider/22.jpg",
          "slider/23.jpg",
          "slider/24.jpg",
          "slider/25.jpg",
          "slider/27.jpg",
    
    
        ];
    
    
    
    
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
    
            appBar: AppBar(
    
    
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.orange,
                        Colors.orange,
                      ],
                      begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                      end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                      stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                      tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                    )
                ),
              ),
              title: const Text(
                "MeaStore",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontFamily: "Sinatra"),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
    
    
            drawer: MyDrawer(),
            body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .height * .3,
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width,
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          height: MediaQuery
                              .of(context)
                              .size
                              .height * .3,
                          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                          viewportFraction: 0.8,
                          initialPage: 0,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                          reverse: false,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                          autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(
                              milliseconds: 500),
                          autoPlayCurve: Curves.decelerate,
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        ),
                        items: items.map((index) {
                          return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Container(
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  index,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                        })
                            .toList(), //////////////////////////////////////    SLIDER
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    
                ////////////////////////////////////////// Sellers under 3 km
    
  
                FutureBuilder<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>>(
                  future: getSellers(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data![index].data()['name']),
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data![index].data()['address']),
                            trailing: Text('${(Geolocator.distanceBetween(
                              _currentPosition.latitude,
                              _currentPosition.longitude,
                              snapshot.data![index].data()['latitude'],
                              snapshot.data![index].data()['longitude'],
                            ) / 1000).toStringAsFixed(1)} km'),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    
    
    ///ORGINAL
    ///
    class CardItem {
        final String mainImage;
        final String title;
    
        const CardItem ({
          required this.mainImage,
          required this.title,
    
    });
    }
```

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code image

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get null data. You can do:

```dart
.distanceBetween(
  …,
  …,
  double.tryParse("${document.get('latitude')}") ?? 0, 
  double.tryParse("${document.get('longitude')}")?? 0, // Just to be sure on parser
);
```

Comment: yes I tried but still showing the error under latitude and longitude

Comment: try like `double.tryParse("${( document.data() as Map?) ?['latitude']}") ?? 0`

Comment: or just `double.tryParse("${document.get('latitude')}") ?? 0`

Comment: return ListTile(

title: Text(snapshot.data![index].data()['name']),
subtitle: Text(snapshot.data![index].data()['address']),
               trailing: Text('${(Geolocator.distanceBetween(
          currentPosition.latitude,
          _currentPosition.longitude,
          snapshot.data![index].data(['latitude'],
           snapshot.data![index].data()['longitude'],
                     ) / 1000).toStringAsFixed(1)} km'),
               );
       }, );  ///the same error is also showing in [latitude] [,longitude][,name],[address]

Comment: try to use the same way